# How to effectively search and replace in Vim by first "testing" or "preview" the search part?

Tags: regex, vim, replace

Sometimes I want to search and replace in Vim using the `s/search_for/replace_with/options` format, but the `search_for` part becomes a complicated regex that I can't get right the first time.

I have `set incsearch hlsearch` in my `.vimrc` so Vim will start highlighting as I type when I am searching using the `/search_for` format. This is useful to first "test"/"preview" my regex. Then once I get the regex I want, I apply to the `s/` to search and replace.

But there is two big limitation to this approach:

1. It's a hassle to copy and paste the regex I created in `/` mode to `s/` mode.
2. I can't preview with matched groups in regex (ie `(` and `)`) or use the magic mode `\v` while in `/`.

So how do you guys on SO try to do complicated regex search and replace in Vim?

Comment: `/c` is helpful, makes me confident I didn't screw things up too badly.

Comment: I use "undo" to achieve this. If my search pattern is malformed, I undo the operation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Test your regex in search mode with `/`, then use `s//new_value/`. When you pass nothing to the search portion of `s`, it takes the most recent search.

As @Sam Brink also says, you can use `<C-r>/` to paste the contents of the search register, so `s/<C-r>//new_value/` works too. This may be more convenient when you have a complicated search expression.

Comment: Okay so once I search with `/`, when I do `s//new_value/`, it only replaces the first searched value. Even with `s//new_value/g` it still only replaced the first value. Also I can't seem to use matched grouped regex like `\1` and `\2` using this method.

Answer (score 6):

As already noted, you can practice the search part with `/your-regex-here/`.  When that is working correctly, you can use `s//replacement/` to use the latest search.

Once you've done that once, you can use `&` to repeat the last `s///` command, even if you've done different searches since then.  You can also use `:&g` to do the substitute globally on the current line.  And you could use `:.,$&g` to do the search on all matches between here (`.`) and the end of the file (`$`), amongst a legion of other possibilities.

You also, of course, have undo if the operation didn't work as you expected.

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious, `:1,$&g` does the replacement on every line. `1,$` means from line 1 to end of file.

Comment: Oops I just found out `:%` means the same as `:1,$`. I've been using it before for `:%s/replace/with_this/g` without realizing what it meant.

Answer (score 5):

As the others have noted I typically use `s//replacement/` to do my replacements but you can also use `<C-r>/` to paste what is in the search register. So you can use `s/<C-r>//replacement/` where the `<C-r>/` will paste your search and you can do any last minute changes you want.

`<C-r>` inserts the contents of a register where the cursor is
The `/` register holds the most recent search term
`:registers` will display the contents of every register so you can see whats available.

Comment: `C-r` generally also can paste from any register.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, added extra details about `<C-r>`

Answer (score 3):

Since Neovim 0.1.7 there is the *Incremental (“live”) :substitute* function. (so this only works in Neovim!)

To enable it set the incommand option:

```
:set inccommand=split
```

It was announced here: https://neovim.io/news/2016/11/